# How can I accept null in the DataTable for bool columns?

Tags: c#

Here I tried to accept null but while creating the header `eachprop.propertyType` is not accepting null.
I want to add NULL values to rows for boolean columns for which I am getting false, kindly help me

```
dt = new DataTable
                {
                    TableName = "ABC"
                };
    
                propInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>();
                propInfos = typeof(ValueInfo).GetProperties()
                    .ToList();
    
                propInfos.ForEach(eachProp =>
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(eachProp.Name, eachProp.PropertyType);
                });
                CreateTableToSqlFromDataTable(connString, dt);
    
                rowCount = 0;
                if (lInput.ValueList.Any())
                {
                    lInput.ValueList.ForEach(eachColumnInfo =>
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        propInfos.ForEach(eachProp =>
                        {
                            dr[eachProp.Name] = eachProp.GetValue(eachColumnInfo) ;
                        });
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    
                        if ((rowCount != 0 && rowCount % 10000 == 0) || rowCount == lInput.ValueList.Count() - 1)
                        {
                            WriteToSql(connString, dt);
                            dt.Clear();
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " | " + "Row copied " + rowCount.ToString());
                        }
                        rowCount++;
                    });
                }
```

this is my class structure:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
private string id;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private bool  b;
    public bool _b
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    private bool? c;
    public bool? _c
    {
        get { return c; }
        set { c = value; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    private bool? d;
    public bool? _d
    {
        get { return d; }
        set { d = value; }
    }
```

I'm trying to build the DataTable from the class properties and value is adding is coming from ui for those class properties. For properties c and d I am sending null from ui and for property b m sending false

Comment: Please don't yell (all-caps means yelling for much of the internet-dwelling population).

Comment: ok sorry... thanks sir for editing

Comment: Side note: I hope `WriteToSql(connString, dt);` uses `SqlBulkCopy`, because it's *much much* faster than individual statements. If it is then the whole "pass 10000 rows at a time" is unnecessary, as it's batched automatically. You could even obviate the datatable and just use a `DbDataReader` to pass straight to the server, the `FastMember` library is very good for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`. You can use a null-coalescing expression for this

```cs
dr[eachProp.Name] = eachProp.GetValue(eachColumnInfo) ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

The cast to `object` is needed to avoid type-inference problems.

---

You also need to update the line that creates the columns

```cs
propInfos.ForEach(eachProp =>
{
    dt.Columns.Add(eachProp.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(eachProp.PropertyType) ?? eachProp.PropertyType);
});
```

Comment: Should i send null or false from ui ?

Comment: Whichever you want. The point of my code is that you could use either, and it will still work, as it re-interprets `null` as `DBNull.Value`

Comment: but it is not accepting null datatype when i am trying to add columns at this part of the code dt.Columns.Add(eachProp.Name, eachProp.PropertyType)'. Do you have any idea how can i solve this part

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: neither `eachProp.Name` nor `eachProp.PropertyType` can return `null`. Only `eachProp.GetValue` can return `null` if the actual property value is null, the property name and type cannot be null by definition.

Comment: Then How can i set the eachProp.PropertyType to bool and accept values Null. Do i need to change my class Structure  private bool? d;
    public bool? _d
    {
        get { return d; }
        set { d = value; }
    }

Comment: Again I'm confused: you can't *set* `eachProp.PropertyType` to anything, it's readonly. If you mean that you should change your class, no what's wrong with how it is now? In any case, you are not *writing* into your class objects, you are reading it and passing it to the database. Is there something that actually doesn't work? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247358/discussion-between-talent-in-making-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var val = eachProp.GetValue(eachColumnInfo);

dr[eachProp.Name] = (val as bool?) == false) ? null : val;
```

Comment: Should I send false from ui or null ? If I send null then in header eachprop.propertyType will not take null

Comment: @talentinmaking you should send `false`

Comment: Even if i send false while creating the column dt.Columns.Add(eachProp.Name, eachProp.PropertyType); it is giving me error Dataset doesnot support System.Nullable